# Can sonar.sources be configured through SonarQube UI so that Eclipse users pickup the same configuration?

Tags: sonarqube

By default SonarQube will not analyse test source sets, so I have configured build.gradle's sonarRunner task as below.

I then discovered that I can setup the exclusions list in SonarQube > Configuration > Settings > Exclusions so that this setting can be shared by the eclipse plugin.

Can sonar.sources and similar properties be configured through Sonars UI for a project so that Eclipse users pickup the same configuration?  If not is there another way?

---

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'

sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        ...

        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java, src/test/java"        
        property "sonar.tests", ""
        property "sonar.binaries", "build/classes/main, build/classes/test"
        property "sonar.exclusions", "<list here>"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

If you want to analyse your Gradle-based project in Eclipse, I can understand that you feel like this is a problem because there's no built-in support for Gradle projects in the SQ Eclipse plugin. Still, what you can do is to duplicate those properties in the SonarQube properties of the Eclipse project (righ-click on the project => "Properties > SonarQube > Preview Analysis Properties").